# Arm/Shirt Rigging

Tags: rigging

I'm currently following Darrin Lile's Character creation tutorial and am at the rigging stage. All has gone well so far, but when I try move the whole arm, the forearm detaches from the shirt. I cant figure out why, as I've been following the tutorial exactly how he's been doing it.

Any advice would be appreciated

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the vertices of the upper arm (the shirt) are correctly weighted to the relative bone, but they are not following the downward movement because they have some weight in others vertex groups that set them more "in place". To inspect this select in edit mode a vertex that should move with the arm bone and look in the propeties N panel all its weights, as shown in the picture.
Once understanded which are the unwanted weights, paint them out in weight paint mode.

[image]