# How to fix a rig deformation on weight paint

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am trying to fix some rig deformation on the wing of the dragon, I thought it would be solved after  painting. But is not. That little part that is circled in the picture does not get dragged when I move the respective rig.

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66686/arm-shirt-rigging/66700#66700

Comment: Sorry, still not understand anything. I did look at the vertices as the link shows but does not clearly explain what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out. It is not perfect but it works. I deleted the previous rig, went to object mode to the armature the to edit mode and Randomly relocated the bone of the wing just a minimal relocation. I regenerated a new rig and it seems that I got a better weight painting this time.  You can see that the wings are down and the deformation of the first picture has disappeared.  [image]